# Cross-validating with two different algorithms on one data set

Tags: validation, machine-learning, training-data

I have a set of classified data with three labels, 'd', 'e', and 'k'. I want to train a classifier to identify 'd' and remove them from the dataset, then identify 'e'. Currently, I'm splitting the data into thirds, which I'll call X1, X2, X3. I train a learner L1 on X1, use that learner to remove 'd' labels on X2, which I then use to train a second learner L2, which I test on X3. Is this a reasonable approach, and is there an accepted standard in this kind of scenario?

Comment: Why do you have to remove 'd' before finding 'e'? Is this to improve performance in some way? (if so, it's not necessarily an approach I would take)

Comment: I actually don't know/can't remember if there is a performance improvement approaching the problem this way. Let me check and I'll post the "results."

Comment: On second thought, I don't understand the goal here. Are you aiming to measure the classifier's performance? or to actually remove 'd' and identify 'e' on some un-annotated data?

Answer (score 0):

Generally there are two popular techniques for evaluating your classifier's performance: cross-validation, which uses the entire data-set (using multiple "folds" of the data), and hold-out set, which excludes some of the data from training for evaluation. Typically, the hold-out set is much smaller than the data used for training (e.g. 80/20 or 70/30).

In this case one option would be to keep a holdout set; do whatever learning and changes on the learning set, i.e. train a classifier, remove 'd' elements, train another classifier, identify 'e' elements; Then test the entire process against your holdout set.